# Getting a date in DD/MM/YYYY format with a string

Tags: c#, datetime

I am having a lot of trouble converting strings into dates.  I know there is thousands of questions online but none seem to be what I am looking for.

```
String fd = "10/05/2018";

DateTime Finish = new DateTime();

Finish = DateTime.ParseExact(fd, 
                            "dd/mm/yyyy", 
                             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
```

This is what I have found online but I am getting back the wrong format.  Basically I am trying to set **Finish** equal to the date set of **fd**.  When I run this code I get this

**Finish = "10/01/2018 00:00:00"**

When I want this

**Finish = "10/05/2018"**

Why is it setting the month to January? Is there anyway anyone that can just show me an effective way, I cant seem to find a direct answer.  Sorry if I seem vague, thanks in advance!

Comment: DateTime contains a time!- and in the parse mm is not months.

Comment: https://nodatime.org/ may be worth a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `mm` means **minutes**, change for `MM` (months):

```
String fd = "10/05/2018";

DateTime Finish = DateTime.ParseExact(fd, 
                                     "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
```

**Edit**: Now you want to *represent* the `DateTime` as a *desired* `string`; you can do it with a help of *formatting*, e.g.:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{Finish:dd/MM/yyyy}");
```

Comment: Right thanks! now I am looking for a way to remove the "00:00:00" at the end of the datetime value

Comment: Thank you very much, you got it working! I'll accept the answer when the timer is up

Comment: @Generic Remember that DateTime just stores a number. No formatting information is stored within it. Any formatting you see is the result of converting it into a human-readable string (as the debugger display, for example, does).

Comment: You can also use `.ToLongDateString();` to get the same result - but you beat me to the punch.

Comment: @Izzy: When printing out in a special, fixed format (`"dd/MM/yyyy"` in the question) I suggest putting it explicitly: `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`